# XSLT appending Ctrl+M character at the end of each line

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform xml doc using xslt. Though I am getting the required result, I am seeing ctrl+M char at the end of the document. How can I ensure additional ^M is not padded just before the end of line.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is not the dos to unix issue. I am running the xslt for a document in linux platform.

The sample output below

```
<variables>^M$
    <variable name="enableLog" value="false" />^M$
    <variable name="enableCache" value="true" />^M$
    <variable name="protocol" value="http" />^M$
    <variable name="port" value="8080" />^M$
 </varilabes>^M$
```

Comment: Please show us the input document, the complete stylesheet code and the complete output document. Obviously, what you have shown is _not_ the output document - XSLT would never produce an `variables` element that ends in `/varilabes`. Tell us how the files were saved, how you invoked the transformation, what flavour of linux you are using, which XSLT processor you are using and what application you use to look at the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you call the Ctrl+M character, is in fact a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), some editors display it as `^M`. If you view your resulting XML in a non-XML capable editor that shows Ctrl-J / Ctrl-M (line-feed, carriage return) characters, then this is the reason that you are seeing these at the end of each line.

It is perfectly valid to use what you call Ctrl-M as a line-ending character in XML. In fact, it is even recommended. Products creating XML, which includes XSLT processors, are allowed to choose between line-feed and carriage return, or both, when it comes down to line-endings. More specifically, from the [XML 1.0 spec (since 1997)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends):

> 2.11 End-of-Line Handling
>   XML parsed entities are often stored in computer files which, for editing convenience, are organized into lines. These lines are typically separated by some combination of the characters CARRIAGE RETURN (#xD) and LINE FEED (#xA).

Since XML is meant for machine reading ánd to be humanly readable, choose an editor that understands XML, like [oXygen](http://oxygenxml.com) or [Stylus Studio](http://stylusstudio.com), even [XML Notepad](https://xmlnotepad.codeplex.com/), or something simple like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) will suffice, they all understand line-endings.

Note: if you really want to remove any and all line-endings, add the following to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:output indent="no" />
```

And make sure that all text nodes are applied, so that you can do the following to remove empty text nodes that are considered significant:

```
<xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]" />
```

However, this will still leave any text nodes that already has newlines. If you need to remove those too, do the following:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#xA;&#xD', '  ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have another issue in the same line. <variable name="threads" value="5" />              <!-- number of threads per process -->  the inline comments are getting moved to the next line in addition to the ctrl+m. any idea on that behavior? is it due to inserting carriage return at the end of the element? how should I preserve that original end of line character

Comment: Please don't ask supplementary questions in comments. Raise a new question.

Comment: @prabhushankar: I agree with Michael Kay, please raise a new question (and follow Matthias advice when doing so). But bottom line is that XML, and by extension, XSLT is not meant for manipulating end-of-line characters, as they are irrelevant in XML. However, after you have applied my solution above correctly, those end-of-line characters will be removed. If they aren't, show what you have done in a new question with a repeatable, minimal example.